# Using Redis pub/sub to invalidate cache entries

Tags: asp.net, caching, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I have an ASP.NET Web application which utilizes Redis (via the totally awesome [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)) as a cache store.

I am also using Redis pub/sub to invalidate these cache entries when they needed to be refreshed (read: cache long, refresh as needed). However, i have been noticing that if the publishers wrote too fast, the web application (subscriber) could not keep up with the messages and the socket connection to Redis would become blocked causing no reads to complete (note: this *may* not be the reason for the socket being blocked, but I drew this conclusion after removing pub/sub from my web application, and the problem dissipated)

Side note: i have left the [PreserveAsyncOrder](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/PubSubOrder.md) option to it's default (true), but i'm thinking i could make this false since i don't care about the order of the messages?

To give you an idea of how this all works, on startup (only once) the web app:

- Creates connection to Redis (single ConnectionMultiplexer)
- Subscribes to a bunch of events

Then, background components publish messages to Redis (say at most 1 or 2 a second), which causes the web app to update (not delete) the cached entry, for example adding an item to a pre-existing set.

My questions:

- Am i mis-using Redis pub/sub here? (should i be using queues for example? or just simply naturally expire the items?)
- How can one make use of SubscribeAsync in a web context, since this should seemingly be done once at startup, and startup lifecycles are typically static?
- Can someone point me to examples of using StackExchange.Redis as a pub/sub system in a ASP.NET web context? (maybe i'm doing something wrong in my code)

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @marc-gravell any help here?

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

Comment: @BasitAnwer - nope :( i've just been using my best judgement

Comment: If your goal is to invalidate cache items, I see no point on using pub/sub. You should probably look for a tagging mechanism, like [this](http://stackify.com/implementing-cache-tagging-redis/), or [this](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis#add-a-single-object-related-to-multiple-tags).

Comment: @thepirat000 - thanks.. but unless i'm misunderstanding, using that approach would require my background components to know which redis keys/tags to invalidate. The trick here is i don't want that knowledge baked into all the different components. I like the abstraction of pub/sub -> e.g "Hey, here's something that happpened!". Then my API just subscribes to that and invalidates... how can that abstraction be applied to tags?

Comment: What do you publish? and how often? Add some code.